# How Did the Breastplate's Chains connect to the Shoham Settings?

Tags: clothing, kohen-priest, mishkan-tabernacle, tetzaveh

[Exodus 28](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0228.htm):25 says

> *And thou shalt make upon the breastplate two rings of gold, and shalt put the two rings on the two ends of the breastplate. And thou shalt put the two wreathen chains of gold on the two rings at the ends of the breastplate. And the other two ends of the two wreathen chains thou shalt put on the two settings, and put them on the shoulder-pieces of the ephod, in the forepart thereof.*

From the text it is evident that the chains are meant to connect to the rings in the breastplate, and to be affixed to the Shoham stone's settings that were on the shoulder straps of the High Priest's apron. However, Gd doesn't elaborate in the text about how the chains were attached to the settings, as opposed to every other attachment of the breastplate to the apron, which was done by way of rings. I looked in Rashi on these verses as well, but he does not explain this detail any more clearly, from what I can tell.

**How were the chains attached to the Shoham settings?** were they soldered together? Were there unmentioned rings?

Please source your answers!

Comment: Did you see Rambam Kli Mikdash chapter 9

Comment: Mishneh Torah http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=85923&rid=7934

Comment: Its fine you can post answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maimonides** (Hil' Klei Mikdash, [Ch.9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/8209.htm):8-13), describes there being two rings on the Shoham settings, onto which the ends of the cable would be fastened. Kesef Mishnah describes the details in law 11 of Maimonides as being 'explained in the verses'. I do not understand where he finds evidence for the upper rings of the shoulder
straps. (**Credit [sam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1418/sam) for source!**)

**Rashi** does not describe any such rings. In fact, while he refers to the chains as being תחובות, inserted throught the breastplate's rings, forming loops, he uses a different word when describing the ends of each chain attaching to the settings, תוקע, affix. His opinion remains unclear.